# How to split dash-separated values in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I get only the middle part of the data in my table? I tried the following code, but this only removes the right part... my output should only be middle part.

For instance when I select the data `1-021514-1` the output should be `021514` without the left and right dashes

```
select LEFT(ticketid, CHARINDEX('-', ticketid + '-') + 4) 
from Table
```

My Data is:

```
|TicketID   |
------------
|1-021514-1 |
|10-021514-1|
|2-021514-1 |
|4-021414-1 |
```

Comment: May be you are looking for a split function. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql) is an example.

Comment: 1-021514 Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. i got this error due to one dash. pls suggest me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select right(left(ticketid, charindex('-', ticketid, charindex('-', ticketid, 0) + 1) - 1), len(left(ticketid, charindex('-', ticketid, charindex('-', ticketid, 0) + 1) - 1)) - charindex('-', left(ticketid, charindex('-', ticketid, charindex('-', ticketid, 0) + 1) - 1), 0)) from Table
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
SELECT
  LEFT(st, CHARINDEX('-', st)-1) TicketID
from
(
    SELECT
        SUBSTRING(TicketID,  CHARINDEX('-',TicketID)+1, 10000) st
    FROM Table
)x
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
with t as (select TicketID  as val)
select t.*,
       LEFT(val, charindex('-', val) - 1),
   SUBSTRING(val, charindex('-', val)+1, len(val) - CHARINDEX('-', reverse(val)) - charindex('-', val)),
       REVERSE(LEFT(reverse(val), charindex('-', reverse(val)) - 1))
from t;
```

(Or)

Use below Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_CTE(@List nvarchar(max), @Delimiter nvarchar(1))
RETURNS @returns TABLE(val nvarchar(max), [level] int, PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([level]))
AS
BEGIN
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT SUBSTRING(@List, 0, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List)) AS val,
         CAST(STUFF (@List + @Delimiter, 1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List), '') AS nvarchar(max)) AS stval,
         1 AS [level]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTRING(stval, 0, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, stval)),
         CAST(STUFF (stval, 1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, stval), '') AS nvarchar(max)),
         [level] + 1
  FROM cte
  WHERE stval != ''
  )
  INSERT @returns
  SELECT REPLACE(val, ' ', '') AS val, [level]
  FROM cte
  RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 1):

hi Ron try this,

```
   declare @string varchar(25)='1-021514-1'
        declare @val varchar(25)
        SELECT @val= SUBSTRING(@string,  CHARINDEX('-', @string)+1,  ((CHARINDEX('-',@string,(charindex('-',@string)+1))-CHARINDEX('-', @string))-1))
        select @val
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT STUFF(
                STUFF(TicketID,1,CHARINDEX('-',TicketID,1),'')
                ,CHARINDEX('-',STUFF(TicketID,1,CHARINDEX('-',TicketID,1),''),1)
                ,LEN(TicketID)
                ,'') 
        from Table1
```